# C# AD user ChangePassword error 0x80070056 the specified network password is not correct

Tags: c#, active-directory, change-password

I'm asking for help about a C# asp net program that change password of ad users.

It works well most of the time, but sometimes i have this case :

Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070056
The specified network password is not correct
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.ChangePassword(AuthenticablePrincipal p, String oldPassword, String newPassword)

This is my code :

```
PrincipalContext ad = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "adomaincontroller", "specificOU", "domainadmin", "password");

if (ad.ValidateCredentials(model.UserName, model.OldPassword))
                    {
                        ModifyPassword("adomaincontroller", model.UserName, model.OldPassword, model.Password);
                        return RedirectToAction("ChangePassword", "ChangePassword");
                    }

public void ModifyPassword(string domain, string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
            {
                user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                some stuf to log error here

        }
    }
```

I can assure you the old password specified is correct. I check it with ValidateCredentials.

So in some case this error hapenned, but ... the user's password is changed anyway, so it works but the error apperead ... I don't undestand.

I saw some threads about this error, speaking about windows KB, but its aparently not my case.

Thanks for help